# Why does my derived class (Stock) give an error?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Product
{
    string title;
    string sirName;
    string isbn;
    double wholesalePrice;
public:
    Product();
    Product(string, string, string, double);
    ~Product() {}
    void setInfo(string, string, string, double);
    string getTitle();
    string getSurName();
    string getIsbn();
    double getWholesalePrice();

};


//Derived Class----------------------------Stock----------------------------
class Stock::public Product{

    double retailPrice;
    char bookFormat;
    int stockLevel;

    Stock();
    ~Stock() {}
    void setRetail()
};
```

So basically my Stock class which is derived wont work...
Also the variable double retailPrice wont work either saying type name is not allowed...

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Product
{
    string title;
    string sirName;
    string isbn;
    double wholesalePrice;
public:
    Product();
    Product(string, string, string, double);
    ~Product() {}
    void setInfo(string, string, string, double);
    string getTitle();
    string getSurName();
    string getIsbn();
    double getWholesalePrice();

};


//Derived Class----------------------------Stock----------------------------
class Stock:public Product{ // use ':' instead of '::'

    double retailPrice;
    char bookFormat;
    int stockLevel;

    Stock();
    ~Stock() {}
    void setRetail() {} // add function body or ';'
};
```

Comment: Silly mistakes 
Thanks !